# Pandas - Conditional drop duplicates based on number of NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I have a Pandas 0.24.2 dataframe for Python 3.7x as below. I want to `drop_duplicates()` with the same Name based on a conditional logic. A similar question can be found here: [Pandas - Conditional drop duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054299/pandas-conditional-drop-duplicates) but it gets more complicated in my case

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
          'Id':    [1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6     ],
          'Name':  ['A',    'B',    'C',    'A',    'B',    'C'   ],
          'Value1':[1,      np.NaN, 0,      np.NaN, 1,      np.NaN],
          'Value2':[np.NaN, 0,      np.NaN, 1,      np.NaN, 0     ],
          'Value3':[np.NaN, 0,      np.NaN, 1,      np.NaN, np.NaN]
})
```

How is it possible to:

1. Drop duplicates for same 'Name' records, keeping the one that has less NaNs?
2. If they have the same number of NaNs, keeping the one that has NOT a NaN in 'Value1'?

The desired output would be:

```
    Id  Name  Value1  Value2  Value3
2   2    B     NaN      0       0
3   3    C     0        NaN     NaN       
4   4    A     NaN      1       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create helper columns for both conditions, sorting and remove duplicates:

```
df1 = df.assign(count= df.isna().sum(axis=1),
                count_val1 = df['Value1'].isna().view('i1'))
df2 = (df1.sort_values(['count', 'count_val1'])[df.columns]
          .drop_duplicates('Name')
          .sort_index())
print (df2)
   Id Name  Value1  Value2  Value3
1   2    B     NaN     0.0     0.0
2   3    C     0.0     NaN     NaN
3   4    A     NaN     1.0     1.0
```

Comment: Works like a charm, it would be nice to have something quicker for bigger dataset tho. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution. The goal is to create two columns that help sort the duplicate rows that will be deleted.

First, we create the columns.

```
df['count_nan'] = df.isnull().sum(axis=1)
Value1_nan = []
for row in df['Value1']:
   if row >= 0:
      Value1_nan.append(0)
   else:
      Value1_nan.append(1)
df['Value1_nan'] = Value1_nan
```

We then sort the columns so that the column with the most NaNs appears first.

```
df.sort_values(by=['Name','count_nan', 'Value1'], inplace=True, ascending = [True, True, True])
```

Finally, we drop the "last" duplicate line. That is, we keep the line with the smallest number of NaNs followed by the line with the smallest number of NaNs in Value1

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Name'],keep='first')
```

Comment: Is this better compared to the other solution? If so, how?