# pandas dataframe drop a row of data with same value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set like below and I want to drop the row of data with same value:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDkPJ.png)

I think I can check the value of all rows, if all are duplicate then drop it, or I can specify a row with specific time (12:30 in this case), but I don't know how to code it...

I tried the following and try to drop just one line but fail..

df.drop['2020-01-29 12:30']

Anyone could give me a push? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't include screenshots, you should create a [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Conditional drop duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054299/pandas-conditional-drop-duplicates)

Comment: In addition to that, the question is not very clear. You should provide an example input and expected output. It seems odd that you'd want to mess up a time series by dropping data, but it's not clear what you consider a duplicate

Comment: Sorry all, shall I post the dataframe here ? I just getting fresh start and don't know how I should ask...

Comment: Hi, don't just post your dataframe here. Be nice: Pot in the effort to Post a minimal reproducible example for us to look at. You will get a good answer a lot faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi let me know if this works for you or not,

Just For example I have created the data frame

```
import pandas as pd

data1={'A':[1,2,3,43],
    'B':[11,22,3,53],
    'C':[21,23,3,433],
    'D':[131,223,3,54]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data1)
df.index.names=['index']
print(df)
```

**DataFrame**

```
       A    B   C   D
index               
0      1    11  21  131
1      2    22  23  223
2      3    3   3   3
3      43   53  433 54

ind=df[df['A']+df['B'] == df['C']+df['D']].index # get the index where values are similar. Here i have done the addition of the values from first two columns and same with next two columns, if both sums are equal then get the index.

df.drop(ind,inplace=True)  #drop row (ind=2) and save the dataframe 
print(df)
```

**Final output**

```
       A    B   C   D
index               
0      1    11  21  131
1      2    22  23  223
3      43   53  433 54
```

Note: index 2 row is removed.

Comment: Thank you very much The Guy! My logic on coding is so bad !
create a variable which can sort out the same value then drop it!
I start wondering how you know what I'm asking...

Comment: @TobyWong no problem Brother.