# Conditional drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I am aware there is a similar question here: [Pandas - Conditional drop duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054299/pandas-conditional-drop-duplicates)

However mine has a different condition.

I have a dataframe: 
`df1`

```
ID          Start                     V_or_D
1           22/02/2020 11:55:01       V
1           22/02/2020 11:55:01       D
2           22/02/2020 11:55:01       D
2           22/02/2020 11:55:01       D
6           22/02/2020 11:55:01       D
6           22/02/2020 11:55:01       D
6           22/02/2020 11:55:01       V
```

I want to drop duplicates based on `ID`. So if the duplicate has a combination of D or V, or D, D, V in `V_or_D`, it will drop the the rows with D's. If for example the combination is D, D it will keep the first and drop the others.

My desired output is:

```
ID          Start                     V_or_D
1           22/02/2020 11:55:01       V
2           22/02/2020 11:55:01       D
6           22/02/2020 11:55:01       V
```

Answer (score 1):

You already pointed out to the solution. With a little adaptation, jezreal's code works like a charm:

```
df = data.sort_values('V_or_D', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('ID', keep='first').sort_index()
```

Input:

```
   ID        Start           V_or_D
0   1  22.02.2020 11:55:01      V
1   1  22.02.2020 11:55:02      D
2   2  22.02.2020 11:55:03      D
3   2  22.02.2020 11:55:04      D
4   6  22.02.2020 11:55:05      D
5   6  22.02.2020 11:55:06      D
6   6  22.02.2020 11:55:07      V
```

Output:

```
   ID        Start           V_or_D
0   1  22.02.2020 11:55:01      V
2   2  22.02.2020 11:55:03      D
6   6  22.02.2020 11:55:07      V
```